# Why is the following commuting rule true when working in normal coordinates?

Tags: differential-geometry, riemannian-geometry

Let $v$ be a smooth function on a manifold and $R$ denote the Riemann Curvature tensor. If we work in normal coordinates, i.e. Christoffel symbols are zero why is the following formula true

$\nabla_i \nabla_j \nabla_k v = \nabla_{j}\nabla_i \nabla_k v + R_{ijk\ell} v_{\ell}?$

I tried to plug this into the definition of the Riemann curvature tensor but I am bit confused about what happens to the vector field $\partial_k v$. Any comments/suggestions will be much appreciated.

Comment: In your formula, $v$ is a scalar function. The $v_k$ on the right should be $\partial_kv$ as should $\nabla_kv$ on the left.